# How to Get url after redirect C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = true }) { };
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
request.Headers.Add("ContentType", "audio/mpeg");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.Headers.Add("Host", "fsa.zedge.net");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,vi;q=0.6");
request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
request.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url,UriKind.Absolute));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseUri = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
```

> An exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred
>   in System.Net.Http.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Response status code does not indicate
>   success: **403 (Forbidden)**.

I have a URL but when I get it, it will move toward the other, and each time a URL is redirected URL, then it's different. And this URL work sessions every time it expires. So now every time I get a new URL, it just informed that the session fails

Comment: Seems fairly clear in the error message. If you request that same URL in your browser, you'll get the same thing. What are you trying to access there?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I want Get url after redirect C#

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to get the URL that you're being redirected to, and avoid the actual redirection? Or do you want to follow the redirection and get the URL even if you get an error (like the 403 you're getting now)?

Comment: Do you know other words except these from title?
You come here to us and you say: "help me". But you don't ask with respect, you don't try to clarify what your problem is and why you want to redirect to the same URL. Don't be a help vampire.

Comment: I'm sorry for unclear question. I have a URL but when I get it, it will move toward the other, and each time a URL is redirected URL, then it's different. And this URL work sessions every time it expires.
So now every time I get a new URL, it just informed that the session fails

Comment: @user3508069 so you want: navigate to the URL which automatically will redirect you to some other URL and address of the last URL you want to get? But you can't, because session expires? If I still got it wrong, could you please write it point by point (in your question).

Comment: Thank  Fyodor very much. I did it. correct version is due to expire. because I used two different variables to the URL request.